# It is possible use tinymce to upload pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, tinymce, tinymce-4

I´m develloping a website that needs to have an upload pdf function.

I´m already using tinymce to insert posts in the website, because its more easy to format, add images, etc.

But I also need to upload pdf, and I dont see any option for that in my tinymce4.

So I came here to ask if somebody there knows if its possible use tinymce for this purpose, or I really need to devellop the pdf uploder step by step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Responsive File Manager](http://responsivefilemanager.com/demo.php) is a PHP based file upload manager that can also be used as a TinyMCE plugin.

Comment: Thank you, I´m trying to put this work but Im having some problems, do you have exprience with this plugin?

Comment: Maybe if you explain what additional functionality you need that can't be provided by a simple file upload input we can find a solution that fits best for your case :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Im just looking for a free plugin that enables to upload pdf and images! Im trying to use this that you said, I follow the documentation to use it on my tinymce4 but its not working. I think everything correct so I´m not finding where is the problem

Comment: If you only want a simple single file upload, why not go with [something basic](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)?

Comment: I know that method but its to a administration panel and I think its more user friendly if I use a good plugin that is already created with  good reputation!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a hidden form.

The HTML:

```
<form id="PDFform" 
      class="hideMe"
      method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      <input id="pdfToken" type="hidden" name="dzToken">
      <input id="fileInput" name="pdf" type="file">
</form>
```

The script:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        selector: "#tinyEditor",
        themr: "modern",
        plugins: [
              "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview",
              "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
              "insertdatetime media table paste image paste"
        ], 
        height: 450,
        force_br_newlines: false,
        force_p_newlines: false,                            
        images_upload_url: 'cgi/editorUpload.exe',
        file_picker_types: 'file, image',
        file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {

                $("#fileInput").click();  // open the chooser       

                var tkn=getToken();       // set any other fields to upload with your file
                $("#pdfToken").val(tkn);                        

                $("#fileInput").on("change",function(){

                    var dataString=new FormData($("#PDFform")[0]);

                      $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "cgi/serverScriptToProcessFile.exe",
                            enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                            data: dataString,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,                                             
                            dataType: "json",
                            error: yourErrorHandlerFunction,
                            success: function(json) {


                                // reset the form or it won't work a 2nd time
                                $("#PDFuform").trigger("reset");

                                // if your script returns JSON you can process it here
                                // mine looks like {"location":"data/editorUploads/test.pdf","alt":"test.pdf"}
                                callback(json.location, {alt: json.alt, text: json.alt });

                            }
                      });                   

                });                         

        },                          
        automatic_uploads: true
});
```

Comment: const json = {
        location: 'https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf',
        alt: 'test.pdf',
      };
      callback(json.location, { alt: json.alt, text: 'hello' });

with this code tinymice treats the upload as video and embeds video with pdf url